# confusion on log4net capabilities, please help clarify?

Tags: c#, vb.net, log4net

My boss is asking me to develop a demo application that uses log4net for logging, and i set up the environment and did a simple logging, but now he is asking me to use log4net to search through the patterns that exist in several log files such us the files that include methods calling each other and then view this on the log viewers, meaning see the relationship between several files. Is he confused between log viewers search and log4net capabilities. because during my research on log4net i only came across the logging techniques it provides but not searching and pattern match that he is asking for.
Some body please explain to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

he is confused log4net is for logging, he is looking for a log analyzer which is outside the domain of log4net something like this http://www.faktnet.com/log4net-dashboard/

Answer (score 3):

Yes in my experience with log4net there is no such capability. It is a logger. Not a log searcher. This is a quote from the apache log4net site: "log4net is a tool to help the programmer output log statements to a variety of output targets."

Comment: thnx i think i need to pass him the documentation for him to understand